# How to resample specific two rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to resample the rows whose `time` column is `'09:00:00'` and `'09:30:00'` into the `row` `'09:30:00'`, `open` takes the value of the `open` column of '09:00:00' row, `low` Take the lowest value of the `low` column of both, `high` take the highest value of the `high` column of both, `close` take the value of the `close` column of `'09:30:00'` row, `vol` take the sum of the `vol` column of the two, and `amount` take sum of of both `amount` columns. Finally delete the `'09:00:00'` row.

Then loop over `code` column and `date` column.

original：

```
   code        date      time         low         high     open    close  vol     amount
0     1  2021-05-20  09:00:00  605.978279   700.473958   617.57   687.26  239  157881.01
1     1  2021-05-20  09:30:00  733.369361  1520.510607  1422.86  1279.49  260  338876.20
```

Expected:

```
   code        date      time         low         high     open    close  vol     amount
1     1  2021-05-20  09:30:00  605.978279  1520.510607   617.57  1279.49  499  496757.21
```

The complete data example is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)


def sample_data():
    np.random.seed(2021)
    time1 = pd.date_range(start='20210520 09:00:00', end='20210520 12:00:00', freq='30min')
    time1 = time1.time.astype(str)
    time1 = pd.DataFrame(time1, columns=['time'])

    date = pd.date_range(start='20210520', end='20210601', freq='B')
    date = date.date.astype(str)
    date = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['date'])

    code = np.arange(1, 100)
    code = pd.DataFrame(code, columns=['code'])

    time1['a'] = 1
    date['a'] = 1
    code['a'] = 1

    data = pd.merge(pd.merge(time1, date, on='a', how='outer'), code, on='a', how='outer')[
        ['code', 'date', 'time']].sort_values(by=['date', 'code', 'time']).reset_index(drop=True)
    low = np.random.rand(len(data)) * 1000
    high = low + np.random.rand(len(data)) * 1000
    data['low'] = low
    data['high'] = high
    data['open'] = data[['low', 'high']].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(x.min() * 100, x.max() * 100) / 100, axis=1)
    data['close'] = data[['low', 'high']].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(x.min() * 100, x.max() * 100) / 100, axis=1)
    data['vol'] = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=(len(data), 1), dtype='int32')
    data['amount'] = data[['low', 'high']].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(x.min() * 100, x.max() * 100) / 100,
                                                 axis=1) * data['vol']
    return data


data = sample_data()
original = data[data.time < '10:00:00']
print(original.head(10))
```

```
    code        date      time         low         high     open    close  vol     amount
0      1  2021-05-20  09:00:00  605.978279   700.473958   617.57   687.26  239  157881.01
1      1  2021-05-20  09:30:00  733.369361  1520.510607  1422.86  1279.49  260  338876.20
7      2  2021-05-20  09:00:00  752.925429  1429.572999  1229.86   841.56  729  953225.82
8      2  2021-05-20  09:30:00  662.160514   803.107665   708.75   729.57  646  510075.14
14     3  2021-05-20  09:00:00   86.629961   218.402500   201.42   169.10  297   64538.10
15     3  2021-05-20  09:30:00  561.272363   578.894955   568.35   567.75  750  432157.50
21     4  2021-05-20  09:00:00  201.850248   962.269683   580.05   361.89  394  113483.82
22     4  2021-05-20  09:30:00  569.305118   698.663747   689.57   573.78  334  193045.32
28     5  2021-05-20  09:00:00  732.225027  1238.944686  1013.71   842.93  818  717606.86
29     5  2021-05-20  09:30:00   69.056275   756.316343   577.08   251.67  384   84376.32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
df = df.sort_values(['code', 'date', 'time']) # sort if required.
df = (
    df.groupby(['code', 'date']).agg(
        {'time': 'last',
         'low': 'min',
         'high': 'max',
         'open': 'first',
         'close': 'last',
         'vol': 'sum',
         'amount': 'sum'}
    )
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
            date      time         low         high     open    close   vol  \
code                                                                          
1     2021-05-20  09:30:00  605.978279  1520.510607   617.57  1279.49   499   
2     2021-05-20  09:30:00  662.160514  1429.572999  1229.86   729.57  1375   
3     2021-05-20  09:30:00   86.629961   578.894955   201.42   567.75  1047   
4     2021-05-20  09:30:00  201.850248   962.269683   580.05   573.78   728   
5     2021-05-20  09:30:00   69.056275  1238.944686  1013.71   251.67  1202   

          amount  
code              
1      496757.21  
2     1463300.96  
3      496695.60  
4      306529.14  
5      801983.18
```